# Can different accounts of windows azure work in one common affinity group

Tags: azure

I wasn't able to see any info on this.

Why I would want this? There are several developers using it's 'own' azure account to have their own servers but all connect to another server (database) on another account. So I think for this scenario it would be good to have all those servers on the same affinity group but there is no 1 azure account but many.

In case that's possible, how can I restrict that database server to allow access only from all those boxes and itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restriction can be made using IP addresses in the Azure firewall. But there is no way to put these servers into the same affinity group. They need to be part of the same overarching account.